# RubyMotion: trying to follow Quartz 2D programming guide for Mac

Tags: objective-c, macos, quartz-graphics, quartz-2d, rubymotion

I'm trying to follow [Quartz 2D programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html) using RubyMotion.

Here's my `AppDelegate`:

```
class AppDelegate
  def applicationDidFinishLaunching(notification)
    buildMenu
    buildWindow
  end

  def buildWindow
    @window = NSWindow.alloc.initWithContentRect([[240, 180], [480, 360]],
      styleMask: NSTitledWindowMask|NSClosableWindowMask|NSMiniaturizableWindowMask|NSResizableWindowMask,
      backing: NSBackingStoreBuffered,
      defer: false)
    @window.title = NSBundle.mainBundle.infoDictionary['CFBundleName']
    @window.orderFrontRegardless

    @view = MyQuartzView.alloc.initWithFrame(@window.frame)
    @window.contentView.addSubview @view
  end
end
```

And here is my `MyQuartzView`, which is supposed to be direct translation from code in the guide:

```
class MyQuartzView < NSView
  def drawRect(rect)
    myContext = NSGraphicsContext.currentContext.graphicsPort
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(myContext, 1, 0, 0, 1)
    CGContextFillRect(myContext, CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100))
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(myContext, 0, 0, 1, 0.5)
    CGContextFillRect(myContext, CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 200))
  end
end
```

I'm getting the following errors:

```
<Error>: CGContextSetRGBFillColor: invalid context 0x10222bad0
<Error>: CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x10222bad0
<Error>: CGContextSetRGBFillColor: invalid context 0x10222bad0
<Error>: CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x10222bad0
```

Why is the context invalid? I'm inside `drawRect` method.

**EDIT**
If I change window rect to `[[340, 380], [480, 360]]` the error goes away, but `drawRect` is not called. However, when I resize window, it gets called with same errors.

**EDIT 2**
This is an OS X app.

**EDIT 3** Interesting, the same program in Objective-C works fine:

```
// main.m
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "MyQuartzView.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    NSApplication *app = [NSApplication sharedApplication];
    NSRect frame = NSMakeRect(100., 100., 300., 300.);

    NSWindow *window = [[NSWindow alloc]
        initWithContentRect: frame
                  styleMask: NSTitledWindowMask | NSClosableWindowMask
                    backing: NSBackingStoreBuffered
                      defer: false];

    [window setTitle: @"Test"];

    id view = [[MyQuartzView alloc] initWithFrame: frame];
    [window setContentView: view];
    [window setDelegate: view];
    [window orderFrontRegardless];

    [app run];

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

// MyQuartzView.m
#import "MyQuartzView.h"

@implementation MyQuartzView

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    return[super initWithFrame:frame];
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    CGContextRef myContext = [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor (myContext, 1, 0, 0, 1);
    CGContextFillRect (myContext, CGRectMake (0, 0, 200, 100));
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor (myContext, 0, 0, 1, .5);
    CGContextFillRect (myContext, CGRectMake (0, 0, 100, 200));
}

@end
```

Comment: are u planing to create 2 filled rectangle . which overlap each other ?

Comment: @rahul_send89, yes, but if I can draw at least one rectangle—that would be a breakthrough. I'm trying to follow this guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html

Comment: if i add a answer down for same .. please don't vote down .
ping me if its not working . will change or del. sound fine ?

Comment: Get the context using ``context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()``

Comment: @rahul_send89 don't worry, I can change my vote any time you edit your answer.

Comment: @ahmet `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext` is an iOS thing, I'm trying to make an OS X app. I will edit my question to make it clear.

Comment: @Halst : NSBezierPath is a part of CoreGraphics . its a optimise way to draw graphics ..
i don't know why your code is not working. have tested the same its working on my machine ...
still cause of down vote :( .. i will avoid answering this questions ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the magic to make it work:  You need to call `to_object` when you get the context:

```
myContext = NSGraphicsContext.currentContext.graphicsPort.to_object
```

---

I implemented your code in a RubyMotion project, and this was the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! What is this `#to_object` method anyway? Can't find any documentation about it.

Comment: I haven't seen documentation for `to_object`. I figured it out by looking at the official OS X code samples.  In particular `PathDemo`: https://github.com/HipByte/RubyMotionSamples/tree/master/osx